# Prove a relation for radius of curvature, using parametric coordinates

Tags: calculus, parametric, curvature

I have to prove that for any curve, the radius of curvature, $\rho$ , the following relation is true where $x = f(t)$, $y = \phi(t)$, i.e., the parametric form is to be used

$$\frac{1}{\rho^2} = \frac{\bigg\{\bigg(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\bigg)^2-\bigg(\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\bigg)^2\bigg\}}{\bigg(\frac{ds}{dt}\bigg)^4}$$

Now to proceed with the proof, I'm trying to use the relation, $$\frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg)^2}$$

But, if I square the above relation and differentiate it with respect to $t$, I end up with $$\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}= \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+ \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$$

Then squaring it, because I want to get the $\bigg(\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\bigg)^2$ term, as is given in the RHS of the given relation, I end up with something much more complicated which doesnt seem to reduce to anything useful. How do I approach this proof?

Comment: Do it geometrically.. that's always simpler. Are you sure you are missing no squares and square roots on the numerator?

Comment: @Buraian Yeah this is the question as provided in our class. And we've been asked to do an algebraic proof

Comment: How are you defining the radius of curavture? If you have an algebraic definition, then this proof will be easier

Comment: @Buraian Its defined as it normally is...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature

Comment: Prove it first in the special case when $t = s$. Once you have proved that case, derive the general formula from a change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$, we set :

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\dot{x}$, $\frac{dx}{ds}=x’$ and  $\frac{dt}{ds}=t’=\frac{1}{\dot{s}}$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\dot{y}$ ,
$\frac{dy}{ds}=y’$,

then the first Frenet formula says:

$\frac{1}{\rho}*\vec{n}=\frac{d\vec{\tau}}{ds}$

where

$\vec{\tau}$ is the tangent in generic point  of the curve line and $\vec{n}$ is the normal line.

In the Cartesian plane, the tangent equation is

$\vec{\tau}=x’\vec{i}+y’\vec{j}$,

the first derivative is

$\frac{d\vec{\tau}}{ds}= x’’\vec{i}+y’’\vec{j}$.

The normal line equation is

$\vec{n}=\frac{-\dot{y}}{\dot{s}}\vec{i}+\frac{+\dot{x}}{\dot{s}}\vec{j}$.

Squaring the first Frenet formula,we have:

$\frac{1}{\rho^{2}}=x’’^{2}+y’’^{2}$

because

$\vec{n}.\vec{n}=1$

$\big(\frac{\vec{d\tau}}{ds}\big)^{2}= \big(x’’\vec{i}+y’’\vec{j}\big)^{2}=x’’^{2}+y’’^{2}$.

That said, we express the formula as a function of the variable t.

$x’=\frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{s}}$,

$x’’=\frac{\dot{s}\ddot{x}t’-\dot{x}\ddot{s}t’}{\dot{s}^{2}}$,

$x’’=\frac{\dot{s}\ddot{x}-\dot{x}\ddot{s}}{\dot{s}^{3}}$,

(because $t’=\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{1}{\dot{s}}$),

$y’’=\frac{\dot{s}\ddot{y}t’-\dot{y}\ddot{s}t’}{\dot{s}^{2}}$,

$y’’=\frac{\dot{s}\ddot{y}-\dot{y}\ddot{s}}{\dot{s}^{3}}$;

and more

$x’’^{2}=\frac{\ddot{x}^{2}\dot{s}^{2}+\dot{x}^{2}\ddot{s}^{2}-2\dot{x}\ddot{x}\dot{s}\ddot{s}}{\dot{s}^6}$,

$y’’^{2}=\frac{\ddot{y}^{2}\dot{s}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}\ddot{s}^{2}-2\dot{y}\ddot{y}\dot{s}\ddot{s}}{\dot{s}^6}$,

and making their sum, we get

$x’’^{2}+y’’^{2}=\frac{\dot{s}^2\big(\ddot{x}^2+\ddot{y}^2\big)+\ddot{s}^2\big(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\big)-2\dot{s}\ddot{s}\big(\dot{x}\ddot{x}+\dot{y}\ddot{y}\big)}{\dot{s}^6}$;

making the derivative of the equation of the differential of the curve arc:

$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=\dot{s}^2$,

we have that

$\dot{x}\ddot{x}+\dot{y}\ddot{y}=+\dot{s}\ddot{s}$,

The sum of the squares of the second derivatives with respect to the variable $s$ is,

$x’’^{2}+y’’^{2}=\frac{\dot{s}^2\big(\ddot{x}^2+\ddot{y}^2\big)+\ddot{s}^2\big(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\big)-2\dot{s}^2\ddot{s}^2}{\dot{s}^6}$,

that is,

$x’’^{2}+y’’^{2}=\frac{\dot{s}^2\big(\ddot{x}^2+\ddot{y}^2\big)+\ddot{s}^2\dot{s}^2-2\dot{s}^2\ddot{s}^2}{\dot{s}^6}$,

$\frac{1}{\rho^{2}}= \frac{\ddot{x}^2+\ddot{y}^2-\ddot{s}^2}{\dot{s}^4}$.